# Eclipse: Add Source to dynamically added class

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, classloader, xdebug

I have a java project that dynamically loads in a compiled class. I want to then step through this class in debug mode, but I can't since Eclipse doesn't know about the source code. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sources are available, you can easilly add them via right click in the desired Jar > Properties > Java source attachment.

Comment: Which jar do you mean? I dynamically load in a .class from the file system and don't have the jar anywhere in the project.

Answer (score 1):

JD-Gui also provides a plug-in for eclipse, that decompiles class files to source code (without comments): JD-Eclipse http://jd.benow.ca/#jd-eclipse

Eclipe just needs to know where the bytecode is located, then it can be used with the debugger to step through.

Comment: I already used it in the way you need it and it worked nearly perfect.

Comment: I already have the source code and the .class file that I can feed into Eclipse - I just don't know where. Can I do that without JD-Gui?

Comment: Ok now I get what you mean exactly. Sure, in your case it would work without JD-Eclipse, but I don't know how to tell Eclipse different classpaths/path-to-sources to search for a dynamically loaded class.
The good thing with JD-Eclipse is that you don't need to set those paths (but - as already stated above - can technically show no comments).